# How to create a Jar file with only project dependencies, without project classes?

Tags: java, gradle

I have a Java project that uses some dependencies, i.e. Commons, HttpClient, SQLite.

I would like to create two build tasks in Gradle:

1. First one would allow me to build a Jar file with only Commons, HttpClient, Sqlite, without my project,
2. Second one would allow me to build a Jar file with my project alone. This is I guess a default build action behavior, so I already know how to do it :)

I also know how to create a Jar file with my project and dependencies together (a "fat jar"), but the resulting Jar file is big with all my dependencies grouped together (~ 14mb).

The reason for my question is that I'm testing the application on a remote server. My thought was that I will upload the 'jar with dependencies' only occasionally, once every few days, when dependencies will change, while uploading the 'application jar' every few builds. Right now I'm waiting few minutes on each upload and I would want to wait few seconds.

Is this possible in Gradle?

This is my current gradle config:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

task fatjar(type: Jar) {
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }

    baseName = project.name + "-all"

    with jar
}

compileJava {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
    options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked" << "-Xlint:deprecation"
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections', version: '3.2.2'
    compile 'org.hjson:hjson:1.0.0'
    compile group: 'commons-cli', name: 'commons-cli', version: '1.3.1'
    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.4'
    compile group: 'org.java-websocket', name: 'Java-WebSocket', version: '1.3.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.5.3'
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpcore', version: '4.4.6'
    compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20160810'
    compile group: 'org.xerial', name: 'sqlite-jdbc', version: '3.16.1'
    compile group: 'org.zeromq', name: 'jeromq', version: '0.4.0'
    compile group: 'com.nimbusds', name: 'nimbus-jose-jwt', version: '4.23'
    compile group: 'ws.wamp.jawampa', name: 'jawampa-core', version: '0.5.0'
    compile group: 'ws.wamp.jawampa', name: 'jawampa-netty', version: '0.5.0'
}
```

*edit*: added more context to the question.

Comment: how about this? https://blog.gradle.org/introducing-compile-only-dependencies

Comment: If a fat jar is too big, why do you think the same fat jar with only your classes removed and stored in a separate jar will be significantly less big? What should this other jar contain (other jars, or classes), and how do you intend to use this other jar file?

Comment: @JBNizet, I'm testing the application on a remote server. My thought was that I will upload the 'jar with dependencies' only occasionally, once every few days, when dependencies will change, while uploading the 'application jar' every few builds. Right now I'm waiting few minutes on each upload and I would want to wait few seconds.

Comment: OK. But why use a jar file instead of a zip file. It would be less ambiguous. You'll have to unzip it to be able to add the original jar files to the classpath anyway. That said, just remove `with jar`, and you'll have what you want, won't you?

Comment: @JBNizet With jar file I can use `java -cp <dependencyjar>:<appjar> main.App` and it will work, since Gradle will pack all my deps into one jar. This way I don't need to unpack anything. And I've removed `with jar` and it seems to do what I want! From some reason I've assumed the 'with jar' was necessary and couldn't be removed. If you'll paste your comment as an answer, I'll tick it as accepted!

Comment: It will if the jar file contains the unzipped original jar files, and not the jar files themselves. But beware that you could have duplicate files, especially under META-INF, that could cause problems when doing that. Why don't you just upload the original jar files themselves?

Comment: Because it's a distributed testing tool that I use to learn ZeroMQ, and I'm uploading it to 6 servers, I don't want to dedicate much time to do dependency management on a target server every time I add/remove a dependency :). Also the 'dependency jar' generated by Gradle only contains unpacked `.class` files, not the `.jar` files packed into another `.jar` file, so it seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just remove

```
with jar
```

from your task, which is what includes the content of your project jar file into the fat jar. See [the documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar:with(org.gradle.api.file.CopySpec[])).

Answer (score 0):

I know your question is about Gradle, but for people who find this page while wanting to do this with Maven, it can be done with the following config for the maven-shade-plugin:

```
<artifactSet>
    <excludes>
        <exclude>${project.groupId}:${project.artifactId}</exclude>
    </excludes>
</artifactSet>
```

Comment: Not sure if there are many people that want to do this, since the question has 0 votes, but thanks I guess ;)

Comment: Yeah. In my particular case, I'm using AWS Glue which requires the program itself be packaged as a raw source code file, but I need the dependencies uploaded to S3 (ideally in one JAR so I don't have to figure out how to list them).